# React-native dev options not showing up on mobile app installed on Xiaomi Phone

Tags: android, react-native

When I try installing react-native app on my redmi note 3 mobile phone, It pops up an error which doesn't happen when I use any other mobile phone. I fixed this issue by disabling MIUI optimization. But after I did this, I'm not getting dev options when I shake my mobile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, for anyone that like me didn't know what to do. The first answer is correct, but I if you are wondering what to do, just like I did, do the following.

1. Open `Security` (an app installed by default on Note 3 phone)
2. Click on `Permissions`
3. Find your app that you've installed using `React-Native`, click on it.
4. There should be a a permission `Display pop-up window` and it will be blocked.
5. Press on this permisson and select `Accept`

This should do the trick. If, you do not see the `Developer options` menu, install your app again (I know I did). Hope this helps,  Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
My divice is Redmi Note 4 - 6.0.1
```

For MIUI 8 you need to turn off the MIUI optimization

for this

```
go to setting >> additional setting >> developer options >> disable "Turn on MIUI optimization"
```

this will install the app in MI device but it will ask for "permit drawing over other apps" permission every time you build the app by command react-native run-android to disable this

```
go to setting >> permissions >> other permissions >> select "permission" tab >> display popup window >> select your app >> accept
```

Comment: addition: if you cant change permission in permission manager. you need to enable it using app called "security" then enable permission manager

Comment: Yeah! Well.. in genymotion and Android emulators, the popup window alert shows automatically.

Answer (score 1):

for XIOMI devices: 
1) Enable USB debugging
2)Goto to developers menu and enable INSTALL VIA USB and USB DEBUGGING (Security settings) ---   this will require you to connect to MI account

--You can run your native app now --

Answer (score -1):

you should set the dialog permission in the XIAOMI phone.

Comment: Can you a bit elaborate on this? I have the same issue, but I need a little more info. How do i set this "dialog permission"?

Comment: Please do add the instructions to your answer as well