# Unable to run react-native apps on Redmi phone?

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, apk

I am trying to upload my react-native apk to redmi note 3 but encountered an error unable to upload some apk after downgrading the gradle from 1.3.1 to 1.2.3 i was able to sought it but still after successfully uploading the app I can only see blank white screen. I am unable to see any app screen.

I followed https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2720 but still didn't found any success.

I have worked on two version of redmi phone one is redmi note 3 with 5.0.2 android version and Mi pad with 4.4.4 android version and faced the same issue on both i.e blank screen.

Comment: is your app opensource? Cause I need to make some research

Comment: Do you get any solution for this?

Comment: @dipali shah. It works when you build a signed apk but during development or testing it does not . There is some issue with gradle version.

Comment: any solution for this issue, I'm facing similar issue with Redmi note 3 and old Redmi with Android 4.4.4, both white screen, I suspect there is somoe issue with Xiaomi permision

Comment: any soluttion for this issue. My phone is Readmi Note 5.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with my Redmi Note4 ( white screen and no develop pop-up menu )

I solved this problem by giving the permission to allow your react-native app to display Pop-up Window. After that the App works fine.

It seems that you may have already solved this problem. If not, hope this answer can help you.

Comment: Hey @Cettoana, can you expand upon the solution?

Comment: Hi @PallavBakshi, may be you can follow the step from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38681923/1593397)

Answer (score 0):

i dont know is my answer suitable or not ,
but i faced this problem , when i tried to root my phone using SuperSU . adb could find my device but i could not installing react-native app . so i restored my phone to before rooting and everything worked good ! 
my phone is Xiaomi Mi Note 3 .